Magento 2.4.5 adding navigation in checkoutpage not working
I'm a Magento dev. I have a problem that luma's default checkout page doesn't show the footer and navigation. I created a custom layout file, I made the footer and header visible, but my category navigation bar was not visible. Can any one help me out? This is my layout file



For Magento 2.4.x, above solution does not work.
Try this:
Edit app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml like this:
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" />
    </body>
</page>

Then add the following code in app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/page_layout/checkout.xml:
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content" />
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container" />
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>

Remove Static Content and Flush Magento Cache.
That's All.

Thanks for responding to me. and and I have edited the code according to your instructions. I Edit app/desgin/frontend////Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml   : 



  and I add file app/desgin/frontend////Magento_Checkout/page_layout/checkout.xml :
but  it still doesn't work

and i attach images result in post
